# How to add SMOTE?

Tags: python, smote

hello I have a largely imbalanced dataset and im trying to incorporate SMOTE before using bert. however im a bit confused as to how it should be done when ive split my data into train, validation and test? since im using textual data does it occur after tokenization?

snippet of code:

```
def tokenize(df):
    input_ids =  []
    attention_masks =  []
    
    for i, text in enumerate(df["tidy_tweet"]):
        tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(text, max_length=SEQ_LEN,
                                   truncation=True, padding='max_length',
                                   add_special_tokens=True, return_attention_mask=True,
                                   return_token_type_ids=False, return_tensors='tf')   
         
        input_ids.append(np.asarray(tokens["input_ids"]).reshape(SEQ_LEN,))
        attention_masks.append(np.asarray(tokens["attention_mask"]).reshape(SEQ_LEN,))

    return (np.asarray(input_ids), np.asarray(attention_masks))

train_input_ids, train_attention_masks = tokenize(x_train)
valid_input_ids, valid_attention_masks = tokenize(x_valid)
```

Comment: I added the [tag:smote] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

SMOTE is a technique to increase the amount of samples in the dataset by adding some noise to the input vector. It cannot be applied directly to the text data, especially, if the text is represented as a sequence or id's of corresponding tokens.

However, it can  be a applied to sentence embeddings or such other representation where the entire sample is represented as a vector of real numbers. But, to my knowledge, I have never seen someone applying SMOTE to text data.

Comment: Also, I have once tried using SMOTE on sentence embeddings, and it did not work.